# Does SQL Server query timeout settings change require a server restart?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to execute a query that times out after 10 minutes. From experience I know that the query takes about 18 minutes to execute. It's not ideal, and this is being worked on, however for now I just need it to execute.

Having changed the `Remote query timeout` parameter to `0`, however, the query is STILL timing out after 10 minutes. I get the message:

```
The statement has been terminated.
Msg -2, Level 11, State 0, Line 16
Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

This is using SSMS on a remote computer. Why is the timeout setting not taking effect? Do I need to restart the server? (This isn't possible right now)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According MS-DOCS you don't need to restart SQL Server.

[Configure the remote query timeout Server Configuration Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-query-timeout-server-configuration-option)

> **Follow Up: After you configure the remote query timeout option**
>
> The setting takes effect immediately without restarting the server.

Answer (score 4):

From the link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177457(v=sql.105).aspx

> The setting takes effect immediately without a server stop and restart

Answer (score 4):

The timeout is a client side setting and below explanation from Microsoft will clear the air why you are still having the issue. Also this setting change does not require a restart. This value applies for an outgoing connection initiated by the database engine.

> The setting takes effect immediately without restarting the server.

The remote query timeout option specifies how long, in seconds, a remote operation can take before SQL Server times out. The default value for this option is 600, which allows a 10-minute wait. **This value applies to an outgoing connection initiated by the Database Engine as a remote query. This value has no effect on queries received by the Database Engine**.

What is the value set for Execution timeout in SSMS for you from where you are running the query:

[image]